# Integrating a fractional power of a rational function

Tags: integration, special-functions, hyperbolic-functions

I am currently working on a project where I stumbled upon the integral

$$
\int \frac{\sinh \left(\frac{R}{2}\right)}{(\coth R - 6R \coth\left(\frac{R}{2}\right) + 9)^{1/4}} \,dR
$$

where $R$ is a real variable. Is there a good way to integrate this? So far I haven't found anything fruitful, what worries me most is the fractional power in the denominator. Thanks for sharing your insight!

EDIT: I have tried the change of variable $\frac{R}{2} = \ln y$ and reduced the above integral to
$$
2^{1/4}\int \left(\frac{(y^2 - 1)^5}{ y^{12} + 17y^{10} - 17 y^8   - 24 y^8(y^2 + 1) \ln y - y^6 }\right)^{1/4} \,dy
$$

I have some hope that this might help. Is there a good way to deal with the fact that the integrand is a fractional power, and with the logarithm in the denominator? Thanks again for sharing your insight!

Comment: What is the antiderivative of an integral ? The integral is an antiderivative ...

Comment: @TonyPiccolo Ooops, of course. Thanks! I corrected it.

Comment: @harlekin "Is there a good way to integrate this?" Numerically.

Comment: Well, can you sketch the project ?

Comment: is it really the best practice to edit this awful-looking integrand into the title?